# JavaScript - Pushing Objects into Array failed

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, array-push

I saw this question being asked a lot but i have not been able to solve it yet, so here goes!
I'm working on a project where i display a list of orders. I want to be able to filter the orders by date. Therefore i'm trying to push each filtered order into a new array, but this gives me the following error:

> "TypeError: filteredOrders.push is not a function"

I've tried to tweak my push syntax as i thought i had it wrong but to no avail.
Each order is returned as an Object. How can i push these objects into an Array? The orders array i am looping through is also a array of objects. Here's my code for a more clear example:

```
data: function () {
    return {
        isFilterShown: false,
        IsOrderDetailShown: false,
        selectedDateFrom: new Date(),
        selectedDateTill: new Date(),
    }
},

methods: {
    applyFilter: function () {
        let dateFrom = this.selectedDateFrom;
        let dateTill = this.selectedDateTill;
        let filteredOrders = Array;

        this.orders.forEach(function (order) {
            if (order.createdAt >= moment(dateFrom).format('DD-MM-Y') && order.createdAt <= moment(dateTill).format('DD-MM-Y')) {
                console.log(order.createdAt, order);
                return order;
            }
            filteredOrders.push(order);
        })
        // this.orders = this.filteredOrders;
        this.isFilterShown = false;
    },
```

Screenshot of console:
[image]

Comment: Makes sense; you're giving it a type, not an *instance* of a type. You probably want `let filteredOrders = []`. (Which is more canonical than `new Array()` in this usage.) Similar to how you correctly set the dates--by creating an *instance*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array` is a function, not an empty array. This line

```
let filteredOrders = Array;
```

doesn't create an empty array. It assigns the function `Array` to `filteredOrders`. You probably want

```
let filteredOrders = [];
```

Comment: (`Array` is always a function--the context doesn't matter :)

Comment: @DaveNewton In TypeScript `Array` can be a generic type or a function.

Comment: But this is JS, not TS. Whatever--it was a nitpick.

Answer (score 1):

The Assignment here:

```
let filteredOrders = Array;
```

is type of just a function and no constructor function is generated.
instead you can try doing this

```
let filteredOrders = new Array(); 
or 
let filteredOrders = [];
```

which will give you access to the Array methods

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/h4xm0w/why-never-use-new-array-in-javascript

Comment: @ThomasSablik if the concept is clear with the javascript Array constructor function life is all easy :) but thanks for sharing the information appreciate that :D